# Is it possible to see which tab is open in the Chrome when your website/web app is open in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, web, web-applications

I want to create a web app(for practicing my skills) that will help in conducting online exams. So I want to ask that is there any way to find out the following things---

- Is there another page opened in the chrome (if yes then which)
- Is there is another application running in the background (if yes then which)
- Is user switching between tabs/applications/desktops etc.

Basically, I just want to create an app that just keeps track of users' activity when the user is giving an exam.
And if you have any of the solutions to the above problems then please tell.

Answer (score 0):

Since most things you want to access are considered private data, it is not directly possible in a Web App, except the page visibility. But you can write a **browser extension**, which is at least allowed to access data within the browser. For information beyond the browser you should consider a native application or some embedded solution like **React Native**, **Xamarin**, or **Electron**, to name a few.

To get the info if the user is currently using the tab your Web App is running in, use the Page Visibility API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

For accessing information about other tabs and browser internal stuff, write an extension:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API